# How to favor Smart Recomposition in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

The Jetpack compose documentation says it can skip recomposition if all the inputs are stable and haven't changed. The definition of a type being stable goes like this...

> A stable type must comply with the following contract:
>
> 1. The result of equals for two instances will forever be the same for the same two instances.
> 2. If a public property of the type changes, Composition will be notified.
> 3. All public property types are also stable.

I cannot understand this clearly. Can someone explain to me how compose checks if a type is Stable?? I can understand if compose determines a type as stable, then it will check for equality with equals method. But how to say whether a class is stable so that we can understand and favour smart recomposition as much as possible?

I tried playing around and found the following.

```
This data class Student is not stable, even if I pass the same instance again, its recomposing


data class Student(
     var id:Int=1,
     var name:String="Anonymous")
```

However, the following class is treated as stable and favors smart recomposition when we pass the same instance again

```
This class is stable when all the public parameters are changed to val

data class Student(
     val id:Int=1,
     val name:String="Anonymous")
```

So, I can understand that all the public properties should be immutable. But to my confusion, the following class is also treated as Stable and favors smart recomposition. Why?

```
This MainActivityVM class is considered Stable when passing like

@Composable
fun StudentList(viewModel:MainActivityVM){
   ...
}

class MainActivityVM : ViewModel() {

   val studentNames = mutableStateListOf<Student>()
   var textInputDialogState by mutableStateOf(TextInputDialogState())

   var publicMutableProperty:String = "This is mutable"
}
```

So, I could not figure out exactly how compose checks for stable types. Can someone help me to understand this so that I can efficiently support smart recomposition in my code?

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot understand this clearly. Can someone explain to me how compose checks if a type is Stable??

These all are stable by default

- All primitive value types: Boolean, Int, Long, Float, Char, etc.
- Strings
- All Function types (lambdas)

Compose compiler looks at the class and the class cannot be inferred as stable if any one of the field is

- mutable (it is associated with a var property)
- has a non-stable type (like lists, map etc.. all data structures are unstable by default, as they are not immutable but read-only)

Also, you can rely on compiler and let compiler tell you the stability of a class when in doubt.

You can use

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:reportsDestination=${buildDir}/composeReports"
        ]
    }
}
```

It will create classes in composeReports, you can check if compose can infer the stability.

```
stable class YourClass {
  stable val value: CornerSize
  <runtime stability> = Stable
}
```

The generated report will look like above in pseudo-code format.

https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/compiler/design/compiler-metrics.md#classes--classestxt